# Token pair liquidity lock expiration

Tags: solidity, remix, pancakeswap

Is there any way to get token pair liquidity lock expiration in Pancakeswap using Solidity? I know how to do this using bscscan.com, but I need to add some condition in my Solidity code to avoid potential scam projects.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find out how to check a token pair's liquidity lock expiration on bscscan.com. It seems were you able to do so, could you please share how you did it?
Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).